# Are Encapsulating Classes Reflective of Swift 3 Paradigms?

Tags: swift, design-patterns

Premises:

- Ideally, the manner in which one programs in a language should try to match the paradigms to which the language ascribes.
- In Swift, those paradigms are primarily protocol oriented programming, and secondarily functional programming.
- For reasons of compatibility and interoperability, Swift also supports object oriented programming.
- Reference types (Classes) are idiomatic of OOP, while value types (structs, enums, primitives) in conjunction with protocols, are idiomatic of POP.

Conclusion: Whenever possible, one should use value types and protocols, and revert to Classes only when it is entirely necessary.

Inquiry: What then, is the role of a Class containing value types? Do these encapsulating classes align with Swift paradigms, or are they holdovers from OOP?

Base Case: Is the following good or bad practice in Swift:

```
struct Attribute {
    let name: String
    var value: Int
}

final class AttributeManager {
    var attributes: [Attribute] = []
    func add(attribute: Attribute) { self.attributes.append(attribute) }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the premises you state are on the wrong track.

Swift is multi-paradigm general purpose language. It does not have OOP just because of compatibility and interoperability. Multi-paradigm languages allow developers to choose most suitable coding paradigm for specific job.

Also, some concepts are not strictly related to single paradigms. Value types are not just functional, they form base kind of types in structural languages. Also many OOP languages that are not functional support value types beyond base primitive ones.

What is called Protocol Oriented Programing is just another form and extension of Interface Based Programming - one of core concepts in Object Oriented Programing.

Your question, about whether or not wrapping value types into the class is good or bad practice cannot be answered because it depends on how you are going to use that class.

Classes and structs have slightly different behavior. Sometimes that difference does not matter so you can freely choose between them, sometimes it does and you will have to use the one that fits your needs.

In your code example main difference between having `AttributeManager` defined as class opposed to struct is sharing changes to its `attributes` field. If you deal with class instance you can pass it around as parameter, and you can make and preserve changes made to `attributes` field across code. Doing that with value type variable is more complicated and it would require either using in-out parameter or returning changed struct through function return value. Classes provide more flexibility here. Also using structs is in contradiction with Singleton pattern where you need to have one and only one instance that can mutate its state.

Each programming paradigm and related concepts provide solutions to specific problems, but they also introduce some other problems. When you are choosing one coding paradigm over another you should choose it in context of problem you are trying to solve.

Further read: [Swift Is Not Functional](http://robnapier.net/swift-is-not-functional)

Comment: It might just be that I am only really familiar with OOP, but from what I can tell, there isn't really a functional / generic way to do what I want: Have a list of Int String pairs that can be added to and have things removed from it, and can store those values to UserDefaults, and later extract them.

Comment: I understand your points about Swift primarily being OOP, but that then begs the question: what are the differences in design patterns that Swift is said to have?

Comment: First, if you know one way to solve a problem, that is a good thing. You solved the problem. That does not mean you have to stop at that point, but you as well might. When you know two or more ways to solve problem you have to see which one fits better and has the least loopholes. Your code is fine.

Comment: Like I said different paradigms are better suited for different problems. Swift gives you options to use ones that suit your needs.